# How to create a new array from an existing array by removing few elements who started with specific strings?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with following data. I need to remove those elements whose value started with `16` or `17` or any other value except `18`.

```
array(24) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "1849781487"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "1838433023"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "1855575775"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "1825054296"
  [4]=>
  string(10) "1868575843"
  [5]=>
  string(10) "1800003509"
  [6]=>
  string(10) "1781354776"
  [7]=>
  string(10) "1650813649"
  [8]=>
  string(10) "1762706044"
  [9]=>
  string(10) "1688111114"
  [10]=>
  string(10) "1669462381"
  [11]=>
  string(10) "1632164916"
}
```

I wanted to remove those elements whose first two digit values are are not started with 18 and create a new array like below:

```
array(24) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "1849781487"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "1838433023"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "1855575775"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "1825054296"
  [4]=>
  string(10) "1868575843"
  [5]=>
  string(10) "1800003509"
}
```

Tried with below code snippet but its not working for me.

```
$filename = "/home/MYSPORTS/MySPORTS/New_Activation/bulk_test.txt";
$lines    = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$searchword = '18';
$matches = array();
foreach($lines as $k=>$v) {
    if(preg_match("/\b$searchword\b/i", $v)) {
        $matches[$k] = $v;
    }
}
```

How could I do this by php?

Comment: Ok, so we have the specification, did you try to write any code yet?

Comment: Yes! I have tried, but that can not achieve my goal. Codes are updated in my post. @RiggsFolly

Comment: Well show us that code, then we can suggest a fix ... **Edit the question** dont put code in a comment please

Comment: Check now please. @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without loading the regex engine like this

```
$input = ['1849781487', '1849784487', '1749781487','9184781487', '1849581487',];
$filtered = [];
$search = '18';
foreach ($input as $in) {

    if (strpos($in,$search) === 0) {
        $filtered[] = $in;
    }    
}
print_r($filtered);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1849781487
    [1] => 1849784487
    [2] => 1849581487
)
```

Comment: Thanks! But your code is printing the last matched element only. Can you please check once?

Comment: Oh, let me check it

Comment: No. I only had one `18....` in the sample code I used. I added a few more and it gets ALL the items starting with `18`

Comment: Thanks! Now its working as expected. Other developers who answered is helpful but they didn't update newly created array indexes value.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is always the first 2 positions a simple substr would work.

```
$filename = "/home/MYSPORTS/MySPORTS/New_Activation/bulk_test.txt";    
$lines    = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$searchword = '18';
foreach($lines as $line) {
        if (substr($line,0,2) == $searchword) {
        $matches[] = $line;
    }
}
print_r($matches);
```

Results in

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1849781487
    [1] => 1838433023
    [2] => 1855575775
    [3] => 1825054296
    [4] => 1868575843
    [5] => 1800003509
)
```

Comment: That's what I read that he wanted. Quoting ` I need to remove those elements whose value started with 16 or 17 or any other value except 18.`

Answer (score 1):

In your regex you use a word boundary `\b` but there is no word boundary between 18 and 0 in `1800003509`.

What you could do is use an anchor to assert the start of the line `^` or remove the second `\b`

You could replace this line:

```
if(preg_match("/\b$searchword\b/i", $v)) {
```

with one of these lines:

```
if(preg_match("/^$searchword/i", $v)) {
if(preg_match("/\b$searchword/i", $v)) {
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/5mWSi)

Or use a regex to match all 10 digits that should start with 18:

[`^18[0-9]{8}$`](https://regex101.com/r/OCjdpV/1)

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/94Unq)

Instead of using a regex you could also use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
$searchword = '18';
$matches = array();
foreach($lines as $k=>$v) {
    if (substr( $v, 0, 2 ) === $searchword) {
        $matches[$k] = $v;
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/nfe4n)